# Creating a new table or updating table HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript that creates a new table everytime a selector changes value. I want it to change number of rows dependent on the value of the selector, so either erase the last table and create a new or update somehow. How can this be done?

```
<script>
function tableCreate(){

var body = document.body,
    tbl  = document.createElement('table');
var rows = document.getElementById("numberOfCourses").value;

tbl.style.width  = '100px';
tbl.style.border = '1px solid black';

for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    var tr = tbl.insertRow();
    var td = tr.insertCell();
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Course ' + i));
}
body.appendChild(tbl);

}
document.getElementById("Course-info").innerHTML = tableCreate();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jquery your problem is very simple. 
You can use a method in jquery .hasClass() on the rows of the element to check for the class and then accordingly delete and create a new table or update the table.

You can include jquery by including the following link at the end of your body in html.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
```

code:

```
if($('#id_of_the_row').hasClass("name_of_the_class")) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Now if you want to update the table record you can do something like this:

```
$('#id_of_the_row').html("your new html table row code");
```

And to delete the entire table and repopulate it you can again use the same method by grabbing the pointer to the table, and rewriting it using the .html() method.

I hope this helps you.